# How can the FIR filter remove the bias?

Tags: filters, signal-analysis

I was reading about Finite Impulse Response (FIR) and I read that it can remove the bias (offset) from signals, but I didn't understand how this can be achieved. Can you please help me to understand the idea behind this?

Comment: How do you define a bias here?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What is a signal bias? It might mean different type of things, starting with a mere offset from its supposed average

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the static bias (the offset from its supposed point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a DC bias is simply a signal component at 0 Hz.

Thus, for example, a high-pass filter can remove that while letting through parts of the signal that are of interest.

An FIR filter can be a high-pass filter.

Comment: Note that any FIR filter whose taps sum to zero will remove signal bias (an exactly equivalent alternative view is any FIR filter whose frequency response is 0 at DC -- the result is the same).  How fancy the filter gets within this constraint is entirely up to you.